# SQL: search for string set

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a table with user IDs and clothing items IDs there's a separate row for every item each user has.

How can I sort out a group of users who has a specific list of clothing items?

```
user_id item_id

1_cph   345 
10_brl  653 
5_cph   345 
2_brl   546 
1_cph   321 
1_cph   235 
1_cph   890 
1_cph   345 
2_brl   321 
2_brl   235 
2_brl   890 
2_brl   345 


Item ID search list:

321     
235     
890
```

Question: Which users have all three items?

**Expected output**
1_cph
2_brl

Comment: share sample data and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Select user_id -- take the user id
from yourtable
where item_id in ('id_item1', 'id_item2', 'id_item3') --that has these items
group by user_id --just 1 report entry per ID
having count(distinct item_id) >= 3 -- it has at least all the items listed
```

you could use `having count(distinct item_id)> 2` to have people that has at least 2 of the 3 items searched